# couchdb views update slow after _design document update:

Tags: performance, couchdb

I'm dealing with a couchdb database, I'm now handling more or less 400000 docs.

I have several views (only map, no reduce), and what happens is that when I want to update just one of them with couchapp, I'm forced to update them all.
In fact, as stated by [How to update a document's record/field in couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132702/how-to-update-a-documents-record-field-in-couchdb), it is not possible to update only PART of a document.

As the database has many docs, the internal updates (building of the b-tree) of all views takes quite a while (more than half an hour).

This is a pretty annoying problem, because at the deployment stage I can't afford to hang the server  to update just one or two views.

So, which is a good strategy to update just one or two views without forcing couchdb to update ALL views?

Maybe there is some way to tell the system to update only some of them... but I don't know how.

Comment: It takes 30 minutes for what to happen precisely? To do nothing more than update a few documents? Your code isn't recreating the views, correct?

Comment: It takes 30 minutes (actually much more) to recreate the views.
What do you mean by "your code isn't recreating the views"? The views are the same but when I update the design document my impression is that the view is re-created even if the code is the same.

Comment: Why are you recreating the views? You shouldn't need to do that unless you want a new "view" of the data.

Comment: If you update a design document, CouchDB needs to rebuild the entire view. So, I'd expect to take it a while to churn through all of the documents and rebuild the indexes.

Comment: ok, but the question is if there is a way of updating JUST one view, without having to recalculate all views. It is apparently not possible as views are contained in the design document, which is uploaded as a single document, and couchdb rebuilds all views even if you just change a ";" in the design document.
Is it right?

Comment: CouchDB will rebuild all views in a single design document, but you can have more than one design document.

Comment: GREAT! It was the answer I was searching for. Many thanks. If you want to add it as an answer (maybe a little bit more elaborated) I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All views within a single design document are later updated when saved to CouchDb. Views are updated on demand (when queried), and unless you want to change the nature of a view, there isn't need to update them normally. You can use multiple design documents and hence views to better control the results of updating the code for a view.

All views within a design document are [updated](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) when any single view is queried, so it's important to consider that when deciding on the structure of design documents and views. To control this behavior though, you can include the `stale` parameter to indicate that the view can return old data. From the docs on the page linked above:

> If `stale=ok` is set, CouchDB will not refresh the view even if it is stale, the benefit is a an improved query latency. If `stale=update_after` is set, CouchDB will update the view after the stale result is returned.