# Secure way to edit Couchdb _user from Emberjs

Tags: security, ember.js, couchdb

I'm writing an emberjs app that uses couchdb as it's backend, and I want to give users the ability to edit some of their user info (their name and emails etc.). I've created a model like so:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    first_name: DS.attr(),
    last_name: DS.attr(),
    full_name: function() {
        return this.get('first_name') + ' ' + this.get('last_name');
    }.property('first_name', 'last_name')
});

App.User = App.Person.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'), // Actually their primary email.
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer', {async: true }),
    teacher: DS.belongsTo('teacher', {async: true }),
    roles: DS.attr(),
    type: DS.attr()
});
```

and I'm using [this couchdb adapter](https://github.com/roundscope/ember-couchdb-kit).

When save the model using `this.currentModel.save();` the save works great, but all of these other properties of a couchdb `_user` just disappear since I haven't defined them in my model:

```
derived_key
iterations
password_scheme
salt
```

This makes it impossible for that user to log in. I know I could just define them on my model, but then they would all be pulled onto the browser, and since these are security essential pieces of information, that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Any ideas about how to get my needed behavior without exposing all of this sensitive information? Or is this information not as sensitive as I think because of good encryption algorithms?

### Update

Couchdb it turns out doesn't support selective updating. You have to provide the *entire* object as it will appear in the most recent version, as shown by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132702/how-to-update-a-documents-record-field-in-couchdb)

Comment: Why does it make it impossible to login?  Username/password should be validated server side.

Comment: The password data is overwritten, since whatever json object the couchdb instance gets in a PUT request at that address is **exactly** the object that it stores. All of these fields aren't in the PUT object, so they don't exist in the most recent update. Perhaps there's a way to make that behavior change? Like only updating specified fields?