# How can I update documents attribute without effect of other attribute in CouchDB?

Tags: php, couchdb, guzzle, couchdb-2.0

I used couchDB with PHP using guzzle to post,put,get and delete data. post, get, delete working fine but problem occur in put. When I send put request document updated with only updated attribute values and all other attributes remove in the document.

I already do post, delete and get data

```
$response = $client->post(
 "/child_installed_apps/_find",
[GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['selector' =>  
['parent_id' => ['$eq' => $userid], 'child_device_id' => ['$eq' =>    
$deviceId], 'package_name' => ['$eq' => $packageName]],]]);
```

Here is the code of put request

```
foreach ($documents['docs'] as $doc) {
    $result = $client->PUT(
   "/child_installed_apps/" . $doc['_id'] . '?rev=' .  
   urlencode($doc['_rev']), ['body' =>  json_encode($app_detail)]);
}
```

Before put request document like this:

```
{
   "id": "1dde9f973b42136c1921bb84d2bca33a",
   "key": "1dde9f973b42136c1921bb84d2bca33a",
   "value": {
   "rev": "1-3ee7bd67f3552f68f7a7c4e4c8b2278f"
},"doc": {
  "_id": "1dde9f973b42136c1921bb84d2bca33a",
  "_rev": "1-3ee7bd67f3552f68f7a7c4e4c8b2278f",
  "parent_id": "PV-407",
  "child_device_id": "2525252525",
  "app_name": "IMDb Movies & TV",
  "app_category": "Entertainment",
  "app_icon": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com    
  /IKW5EWVX4qUYF6LPP1_O1sWiZsMblSQVnBrtkMAd07Br69lEApDez9yzFe09iAgJAg=s180-rw",
  "package_name": "com.android.imdb",
  "app_status": "0",
  "all_block_app_status": "0",
  "timely_status": "0",
  "monday": "00:00",
  "tuesday": "00:00",
  "wednesday": "00:00",
  "thursday": "00:00",
  "friday": "00:00",
  "saturday": "00:00",
  "sunday": "00:00",
  "app_datetime": "2019-01-15 17:20:46"
}
```

and after request document like this:

```
{
   "id": "378647beffcb869ab4ad831196666059",
   "key": "378647beffcb869ab4ad831196666059",
   "value": {
   "rev": "4-949230091e577dc3d89725836d35a71b"
  },"doc": {
     "_id": "378647beffcb869ab4ad831196666059",
   "_rev": "4-949230091e577dc3d89725836d35a71b",
   "app_status": "1"
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a document's record/field in couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132702/how-to-update-a-documents-record-field-in-couchdb)

Comment: You must send the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make partial updates you can use an update handler:

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/ddocs.html#update-functions

**Step 1. Create a design document with your update handler**

Following update handler will update the status property of a document and set the updated_at property to the current time.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/myDesign",
  "updates": {
    "setStatus": "function(doc, req) {
                    // Use JSON.parse(req.body) if you use POST
                    doc.status = req.query.status
                    doc.updated_at = new Date().toISOString()
                    doc.updated_by = req.userCtx.name
                    return [doc, "Status was set to " + doc.status_]
                  }"
  }
}
```

**Step 2. Call the update handler**

```
GET /db/_design/myDesign/_update/setStatus/my_doc?status="NEW STATUS"

// Returns: "Status was set to NEW STATUS"
```

**Caveats**

As you can see the update handler is a great tool for partial updates or updates where you don't want to make a roundtrip to retrieve the document with its current revision first.

**Warning: This method is is not conflict free and you still can introduce conflicts.**