# How to edit a particular record inside a Couchdb's document

Tags: nosql, couchdb, pouchdb

We have a document which has 50k records.

We are trying to edit a particular record from the document but when we do it the whole documents gets overwritten.

How can we edit a record from the document without losing all the data from the same document?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do partial update of a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132702/how-to-do-partial-update-of-a-document)

Comment: No, not exactly. According to that link, it is not possible to edit.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's not possible to do a partial update.